# How can I calculate whether our Free Throw Percentage improved over the season, and the confidence level?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval

I was keeping track of our team free throw percentage throughout our practice days.  Sometimes we shot many sets within one day.

How can I calculate whether our Free Throw Percentage method improved over the season, and the confidence level of this method?

Was this method effective and how high is the confidence that this method improved our free throw shooting?

[File with Free Throw Makes and Takes](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eTxBYtepvzYEvWIqSfsB_CdBYlUKn0or0Pww3TaDPmU/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

Without doing any statistical analysis, I would start by plotting it.

I don't know anything about basketball, but I am assuming that Makes is # successes and Takes is the # trials.

A simple plot shows there is very little difference at the start to at the end. Maybe a slight increase, but you aren't going to find statistical significance by any test.

[image]